# How to make a discord bot give a role to someone

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

For example I have a bot on the server and it has admin permissions and I want to give admin role to anyone who says in the chat the secret phrase like 'abc' for example

This is the code by now:

```
if message.content == "caca":
           role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="CEO")
           await client.add_roles(message.author.id, role)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as `client.add_roles` anymore, it's `Member.add_roles`

```py
role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="YOUR ROLE NAME")
await message.author.add_roles(role)
```

Next time instead of asking a question you should look at the docs. Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the *last step* in your process for finding an answer.

#### Reference:

- [`Member.add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles)

Comment: Dude that wasn't useful

Comment: if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == 'cacaos':
        role = client.get(server.roles, name='CEO')
        await message.author.add_role('CEO')

Comment: AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: It's supposed to be a role object, not a string

Comment: Let me edit my answer... I cannot believe you actually need help with this, is literally the basics

Comment: Also you need intents.members and intents.guilds

Comment: what is intents?

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: Yeah issue with intents, take a look at this https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html enable default + members